# callback claim that val_loss did not improve, while it clearly show that it did

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

When I was train on a dataset and I set `ModelCheckpoint` call back to save the model. The weird thing is that: `val_loss` clearly improve ( showing in the log ) but the callback claim that it doesn't improve and thus doesn't save my model at all.

Here is my code:

```py
model_checkpoint_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    filepath=checkpoint_filepath,
    save_weights_only=True,
    mode = 'max',
    verbose=1,
    save_best_only=True)

early_stop_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=40,verbose=1)
reduce_lr = tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(patience=5, min_lr=1e-5,verbose=1)
callbacks = [model_checkpoint_callback,early_stop_callback,reduce_lr]
```

```
model.fit(x=train_generator,
          epochs=1000,
          steps_per_epoch=len(train_generator)//3,
          validation_data=valid_generator,
          validation_steps=len(valid_generator),verbose=1,
          class_weight=class_weights,
          callbacks=callbacks)
```

And here is the output:
[image]

And when the val_loss increase, It claim that the val_loss improve? What is happening? oh and I am using tensorflow_rocm 2.2.0, but I don't think that matter though ...

Answer (score 0):

This is so embarrassing, I set the mode to max, which inform the model to be saved only when val_loss increase ... I will leave the question here so that other people won't repeat my silly error ( doubt that any would though ... )

Answer (score 0):

Obviously overfitting, let's add some dropout and regularization.